# I am trying to use google speech to text api I am getting error: contentExceptions#media-stream

Tags: speech-to-text

I am trying to use google speech to text api I am getting error: Permission to use microphone is blocked. To change, go to chrome://settings/contentExceptions#media-stream
can any one help how to resolve this.

Comment: Have you tried going to the suggested URL by pasting it into the Chrome address bar??

Comment: yes its ---https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html